# Clearcase UCM- Creating components with same name but different root directory

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

we have 5 vobs and each vob has 2 directories 'client' and 'core' within it.

For eg:

```
/vobs/vob1/client
/vobs/vob1/core
/vobs/vob2/client
/vobs/vob2/core
```

and so on..

We want to make client and core as components of vob1 and then client and core as components of vob2 in the same project. Is there a way to do this? Because when I tried it it complained of same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can have `client1` and `client2` in the same UCM project, since their root path would be different.

However, their UCM component name must also be different, especially if vob1 and vob2 have the same UCM Admin Vob (Ie the same pvob).

The [`cleartool mkcomp`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkcomp.htm) page does mention:

> **The component name must be unique within the PVOB**.
>   All UCM objects share the same namespace. You will get an error if the name you provide collides with the name of an existing UCM object, for example, a project.